# Из JSON в HTML код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть JSON.

```js
{
  "body": {
    "div": [{
      "class": "row-fluid",
      "style": "z-index: 27;",
      "div": [{
        "class": "span6 droppedFields",
        "style": "z-index: 28;",
        "div": {
          "class": "droppedField",
          "name": "textID",
          "style": "z-index: 29;",
          "id": "CTRL-DIV-1001",
          "label": {
            "class": "control-label",
            "#text": "Text"
          },
          "input": {
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "Text here...",
            "class": "ctrl-textbox"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "class": "span6 droppedFields",
        "style": "z-index: 30;",
        "div": {
          "class": "droppedField",
          "style": "z-index: 31;",
          "id": "CTRL-DIV-1002",
          "label": {
            "class": "control-label",
            "#text": "Email"
          },
          "input": {
            "type": "email",
            "placeholder": "useremail.com",
            "class": "ctrl-textbox"
          }
        }
      }]
    }, {
      "class": "row-fluid",
      "style": "z-index: 32;",
      "div": {
        "class": "span12 action-bar droppedFields",
        "style": "min-height: 80px; z-index: 33;",
        "div": {
          "class": "droppedField",
          "style": "z-index: 41;",
          "id": "CTRL-DIV-1003",
          "label": {
            "class": "control-label",
            "#text": "Password"
          },
          "input": {
            "type": "password",
            "placeholder": "Password...",
            "class": "ctrl-passwordbox"
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

есть ли возможность построить HTML из этого JSON? и что для этого лучше использовать?

Comment: [http://json2html.com](http://json2html.com) Вот тут построили похожую штуку , [http://stackoverflow.com/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json) Тут активно обсуждали , Ну и вообще идея не нова , много кто юзает так или иначе .

Comment: А как с повторяющимися тегами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал javascript и просто написал свою рекурсивную функцию которая обрабатывала бы JSON. например:

```
function JSONtoSTR(obj, parenttag){ //преобразовываем объект в строку
 if (!parenttag) parenttag = ""; //для повторяющихся тегов
 var str = ""; //в этой переменной будем собирать нашу строку
 for (var i in obj) { //перебираем все элементы в нашем объекте
  if (typeof (obj[i]) == "object") { //если текущий элемент объект (тег)
   var params = ""; //под параметры для тега
   var tag = i; //имя тега
   for (var param in obj[i]) //собираем все параметры для тега
    if (typeof (obj[i][param]) != "object") params += " "+param+"='"+obj[i][param]+"'"; //если текущий элемент не объект, значит это параметр
    if (isNaN(parseInt(i))) //если текущий элемент не число
     str += "<" + tag + params + ">"; //записываем тег и его параметры
    else { //если элемент числовой, значит имя текущего тега находится во 2 параметре нашей функции
     tag = parenttag; //берем предыдущий тег
     str += "<" + parenttag + params + ">";
    }
    str += JSONtoSTR(obj[i], tag); //вызываем еще раз нашу функцию для следующего объекта
    str += "</" + tag + ">"; //закрываем текущий тег
  }
 }
 return str; //возвращаем готовую строку
}

document.open();
document.write(JSONtoSTR(JSON));
document.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я нашел готовые библиотеки для преобразования json в html (https://github.com/Jxck/html2json) но результата добиться так и не смог.

Comment: Готовые библиотеки не всегда подходят под конкретный случай. Только написание функции обработки вручную дает 100% результат. :)

Comment: @Max правильнее писать `for (var i in obj)`, нежели `for (i in obj)`

Comment: @mix согласен, хотя javascript такое прощает.

Comment: @Max главное, чтобы браузеры прощали, не все из них понимают такой синтаксис и некоторые выдают ошибку. Во избежание этого, лучше подстраховаться и объявить все переменные.

Answer (score 1):

> есть ли возможность построить HTML из этого JSON?

Есть.

> и что для этого лучше использовать?

javascript, jquery. Вообще, зависит от того, где вы этот Json получаете. Возможно, есть смысл и на серверной стороне это сделать при помощи языка, используемого на сервере.